# Каким образом нужно передать self объекта b класса B при вызове a.inc()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно начал изучать python и столкнулся с проблемой. 
Например:

```
 class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.count= 1

        def setCount(self,count):
            self.count+=count

    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.b = B

        def inc(self):
            self.b.setCount(20)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = A
        a.inc()
```

Выдает ошибку
TypeError: inc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Каким образом  нужно передать self объекта b класса B при вызове a.inc() .

Comment: Конструктор-то надо вызвать `a = A()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1

    def setCount(self, count):
        self.count += count


class A:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.b = obj

    def inc(self):
        self.b.setCount(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    a = A(b)
    a.inc()
    print(b.count)
```